# Make two expressions look alike OR check that they are the same

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, expression-test, expression-form

I would like to compare my Mathematica calulations with the results from a paper.

I get:

```
myRes= (b/g)^0.25 + (0.25*(b/g)^0.25*w[x])/g + (b*((-0.09375*b)/(b/g)^1.75 + (0.25*g)/(b/g)^0.75)*w[x]^2)/g^4 + (0.1171875*b^3*w[x]^3)/((b/g)^2.75*g^6) + 
 ((0.12646484375*b^4)/((b/g)^3.75*g^8) - (0.03125*(b/g)^0.25)/g^4)*w[x]^4
```

The paper gets:

```
paperRes = b^0.25*(g^(-0.25) + (0.25*w[x])/g^1.25 + (0.15625*w[x]^2)/g^2.25 + (0.1171875*w[x]^3)/g^3.25 + (0.09521484375*w[x]^4)/g^4.25)
```

**I want to be sure that those two expressions are actually the same.
How can I do it ?**

I already tried: `Reduce[myRes==paperRes]` but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assume that `b > 0` and `g > 0`

```
myRes = (b/g)^0.25 + (0.25*(b/g)^0.25*w[x])/
     g + (b*((-0.09375*b)/(b/g)^1.75 + (0.25*g)/(b/g)^0.75)*w[x]^2)/
     g^4 + (0.1171875*b^3*w[x]^3)/((b/g)^2.75*
       g^6) + ((0.12646484375*b^4)/((b/g)^3.75*g^8) - (0.03125*(b/g)^0.25)/
        g^4)*w[x]^4 // Rationalize // Simplify[#, b > 0 && g > 0] &

(* (1/(2048 g^(17/4)))b^(
 1/4) (2048 g^4 + 512 g^3 w[x] + 320 g^2 w[x]^2 + 240 g w[x]^3 + 195 w[x]^4) *)

paperRes = 
 b^0.25*(g^(-0.25) + (0.25*w[x])/g^1.25 + (0.15625*w[x]^2)/
       g^2.25 + (0.1171875*w[x]^3)/g^3.25 + (0.09521484375*w[x]^4)/g^4.25) // 
   Rationalize // Simplify[#, b > 0 && g > 0] &

(* (1/(2048 g^(17/4)))b^(
 1/4) (2048 g^4 + 512 g^3 w[x] + 320 g^2 w[x]^2 + 240 g w[x]^3 + 195 w[x]^4) *)

myRes == paperRes

(* True *)
```

Comment: Wow, nice answer ! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

**Very simple method:** Just plot both functions for some chosen constants and see if they have the same shape. Of course, this is not a general proof that the functions are the same, but sometimes it is sufficient.

```
myRes= (b/g)^0.25 + (0.25*(b/g)^0.25*w[x])/g + (b*((-0.09375*b)/(b/g)^1.75 + (0.25*g)/(b/g)^0.75)*w[x]^2)/g^4 + (0.1171875*b^3*w[x]^3)/((b/g)^2.75*g^6) + 
 ((0.12646484375*b^4)/((b/g)^3.75*g^8) - (0.03125*(b/g)^0.25)/g^4)*w[x]^4;

paperRes = b^0.25*(g^(-0.25) + (0.25*w[x])/g^1.25 + (0.15625*w[x]^2)/g^2.25 + (0.1171875*w[x]^3)/g^3.25 + (0.09521484375*w[x]^4)/g^4.25);

a = Plot[myRes /. {w[x] -> x, b -> 1, g -> 2}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thin}];
b = Plot[paperRes /. {w[x] -> x, b -> 1, g -> 2}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Red, Thickness[0.01]}];

Show[a,b]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is also a great method.